# MVC3 Autocomplete and POST Method in Controller

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, autocomplete

I got a MVC Razor View page as a form for people to enter details and submit to a database.
It works using dropdownlist but I want to add a autocomplete textbox to the form.
This works fine however when posting back to the POST controller it sets the ID of the person to 0 always. Any ideas?

Thanks

Javascript:

```
 script type="text/javascript">

   $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#PersonName").autocomplete({
            source: '@Url.Action("AutocompleteSuggestions")',
            minLength: 2,

            select: function (event, ui) {
                if (ui.item) {
                    $("#PersonName").val(ui.item.label);
                    $("#PersonId").val(ui.item.value);
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Controller:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(MappingModel view)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var entity = new PersonContempancy();
            entity.PersonId = view.PersonId;
            entity.FrameworkId = view.FrameworkId;
            entity.ContempancyCategoryId = view.ContempancyCategoryId;
            entity.ContempancyId = view.ContempancyId;
            entity.ContempancyLevelId = view.ContempancyLevelId;
            entity.FrameworkLevelId = view.FrameworkLevelId;
            db.PersonContempancies.Add(entity);
            db.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Index");  
        }



        ViewBag.Contepancies = db.Contempancies.ToList();
        ViewBag.ContempancyCategory = db.ContempancyCategories.ToList();
        ViewBag.ContempancyLevel = db.ContempancyLevels.ToList();
        ViewBag.FrameworkLevel = db.FrameworkLevels.ToList();
        ViewBag.Person = db.People.ToList();
        ViewBag.Framework = db.Frameworks.ToList();



        return View();
    }

  public ActionResult AutocompleteSuggestions(string term)
    {

        var namelist = db.People.Where(c => c.PersonName.Contains(term)).Select(c => new { value = c.PersonId, label = c.PersonName}).Distinct().Take(10);

        return Json(namelist.ToArray(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

Comment: How is the PersonID related to the autocomplete functionality? Does idCat represent the PersonID?

Comment: sorry ignore idcat i removed it it was failed test. PersonId is used to get a list of users from the database for the autocomplete. it sends it to the autocomplete method in the controller. Do you want me to post that method also? I need the ID to be passed to the model in the controller so it can post to the database.

Comment: Yes, that would be useful. The more info the better..

Comment: Done :) added it to the bottom of the controller code.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your AutoCompleteSuggestions code it looks like you are only sending back the person name, not the person's id, when returning your JSON. If i'm understanding correctly you need to return both the name and the ID and set the person id via JQuery in the select function in your autocomplete function. It should look (roughly) something like this:

```
var namelist = (from c in db.People where c.PersonName.Contains(term) select new { c.PersonName, c.PersonID}).Distinct().Take(10).ToArray();
return Json(namelist.ToArray(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

and

```
     $("#searchTerm").val(ui.item.value.PersonName);
     $("#PersonID").val(ui.item.value.PersonID);
```

Comment: ok thanks will try that out tomorrow. I did look in the stack and find it was sending the name twice when I needed to send name and id.

Comment: just a update, that breaks the autocomplete. I get no suggestions when I make that change to the script.

Comment: I got the method sending both the ID and Name to the JS but no matter what lables I use, the autocomplete suggests the correct name but as soon as I clikc the name it changes the textbox to the ID instead. updated code added.

Comment: What do you see when you set a debugger in the select function and view the contents of ui.item?

Comment: I see label is persons name and value is persons ID as it should be working. I never done JS so confused on how to select it. werid thing is if I comment out the select function varibles then it still works.

Comment: anyone else got any suggestions?